# Is it good to generate dynamic keywords every time when page loaded?(SEO)

Tags: html, keyword

For an example generate 10 random keywords from web content.

Thanks..

UPDATED.
For SEO.

Comment: Keywords used for what? If SEO, "random" doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: yes,FOR SEO.Generate random keywords from web content...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create content that people would want to read?

Comment: Questions about SEO are a better fit on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm trying to understand "What" is better to use for dynamic content"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean for display ...

The only advantage I can think of is that search engines might possibly go "This page is updated frequently, we should check it more often", maybe.  I'm not up enough on the latest search engine workings to say if this would actually work or not.  I wouldn't trust it to.

Disadvantages depend on usage, but I can't picture any scenario where it's immensely helpful to be "random".  If you better describe the reasoning that led you to this conclusion, we can tell you whether it's right or not.  My gut feeling however is ... no.  If you want to display summary data, then "random" shouldn't fit into the equation, or at least, not at the top level.  You should first filter the content based on some useful criteria, then apply random at the last step if necessary.

**Example Process:**

1. Filter out words on the stop list (if, is, you, etc).
2. Count occurences of words, prefer words with high occurence counts.
3. Prefer words which aren't featured prominently in other content items.
4. If there are more than 10 words remaining, randomly select 10 from the better scorers.

Keywords for this post: I, of, is, it, to, but, you, on, we, if.

Comment: I have 6 random texts on my web page. keywords for example: bot, quiz, entertainment, artificial, chat, attachment, feeling, visiting, lifetalk, full, emotion, famous, apartments, bridges

Comment: But are those words random, and from the web content itself, or are they randomly selected from a list of keywords for the site?  You could give the search engines a real headache if they pay attention to the keywords, and your selection is truly random.  What if you randomly put the "quiz" keyword on a page which has nothing to do with quizzes?

Comment: I have my web portfolio.On my  main page I have recently 6 added works from database(works with descriptions).I have created a php script ,php script generaeted keywords from 6 texts more then 100 keywords.When page loaded ,sript randomly generate 10 keywords from 100.

Comment: Why do you want random keywords though, what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I hoping to achieve more people.With static keywords I had less then 10 people per month.I did a lot of SEO solutions with html structure  like <h1>,<h2><alt> etc..

Comment: Some people say yes, some people say no, and the search engines won't tell you how they work ... ... I think there was a bit of confusion in the question.  It sounded like you wanted to take random words from your page content and use those as keywords, which would be bad.  My recommendation ... try it, see what happens ... but things with search engines can take a while to kick in.  Alternatively, yes, ask on the webmasters.stackexchange.com site, they may be able to give better help.